# How can query with a false "where" condition return results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a query. The `Where` clause contains two parts both of them are false (because @Notify is not equal to 13005 or 13105).

But this query returns 36 rows. How can it return anything if where block contains false? CHECKDB shows no errors, restart also doesn't help. If I add 1 = 0 condition instead of @Notify = 13005 then query return 0 rows.

> SQL SERVER Version - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22
>   (Intel X86) 
>         Jul  9 2008 14:43:34 
>         Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
>         Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64)

```
declare @Notify smallint
set @Notify = 20

select distinct DMD_ID
    ,cast(DMD_Document as varchar) + '-' + cast(Cl_Place as varchar) as DMD_Document
    ,DMD_Client
from DocMoveDemand
inner join Client on DMD_Client = Cl_ID
inner join DocMoveDemandList on DMDL_SDoc = DMD_ID
left outer join DocOut on DO_DocMoveDemand = DMD_ID
where (
        @Notify = 13005
        and DMDL_DocMoveDenyReason in (2,3,4)
        and (
            DO_IsMove = 'Y'
            or DMD_IsReturn = 1
            )
        and DateDiff(DD, isnull(DMD_DateReturn, DO_DateMove), GETDATE()) < 14
        and DMD_NotifyInv1 = 0
        )
    or (
        @Notify = 13105
        and DMDL_DocMoveDenyReason in (2,3,4)
        and (
            DO_IsMove = 'Y'
            or DMD_IsReturn = 1
            )
        and DateDiff(DD, isnull(DMD_DateReturn, DO_DateMove), GETDATE()) >= 14
        and DMD_NotifyInv2 = 0
        )
order by DMD_ID
```

Execution plan
[image]

Here is a plan with direct comparison https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1hTRr59W and with `(SELECT @Notify)` https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hk27lI9cW

Comment: Please post execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Try changing `@Notify = 13005` to `(SELECT @Notify) = 13005` and the same for second.

Comment: @lad2025 added plan to post

Comment: @lad2025 with (SELECT @Notify) query return 0 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with (SELECT @Notify) query return 0 records

Based on your version `SQL SERVER 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Services` I guess it is a bug. Direct comparison does not work

```
@Notify = 13005
```

but

```
(SELECT @Notify) = 13005
```

behaves as it should.

---

I would also try:

- setting [Forced Parametrization](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2935/sql-server-simple-and-forced-parameterization/) for original query.
- restoring your DB on modern SQL Server 2012+

Comment: Here is a plan with direct comparison https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1hTRr59W and with select https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hk27lI9cW

Comment: Forced parametrization didn't help, so I guess the problem is in old version. I should install all service packs or maybe upgrade sql server version. Thanks!

Comment: Specifically the bug is this one which was fixed https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/377268/condition-in-where-clause-incorrectly-pushed-to-key-lookup-for-outer-join

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this looks like a query optimizer bug ([specifically this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/377268/condition-in-where-clause-incorrectly-pushed-to-key-lookup-for-outer-join)) which was [fixed in CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/958186/cumulative-update-package-2-for-sql-server-2008) (*FIX: Query could return incorrect results if a passthrough predicate is used with a filter in its query plan*). The evaluation of this bit of the `WHERE` predicate is incorrectly pushed into a key lookup against `DocOut` and not evaluated against rows that didn't match anything in `DocOut` and are preserved by the outer join.

The lookup operator below (numbered 4) has a seek predicate of

```
Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocOut].DO_ID 
               = Scalar Operator([SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocOut].[DO_ID])
```

and a residual predicate of

```
( [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocOut].[DO_IsMove] = 'Y'
   OR [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocMoveDemand].[DMD_IsReturn] = ( 1 ) )
AND ( [@Notify] = ( 13005 )
      AND datediff(day, CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime, isnull([SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocMoveDemand].[DMD_DateReturn], [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocOut].[DO_DateMove]), 0), getdate()) < ( 14 )
      AND [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocMoveDemand].[DMD_NotifyInv1] = ( 0 )
       OR [@Notify] = ( 13105 )
          AND datediff(day, CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime, isnull([SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocMoveDemand].[DMD_DateReturn], [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocOut].[DO_DateMove]), 0), getdate()) >= ( 14 )
          AND [SMNikopol].[dbo].[DocMoveDemand].[DMD_NotifyInv2] = ( 0 ) )
```

[image]

1. There are 215 rows going in to the left outer join on `DocOut`
2. 179 of them matched a single row in the table. This seek operator returns a system generated column called `IsBaseRow1010` along with the ID column from the table.
3. The nested loops operator performing the key lookup has a pass through predicate on `IsBaseRow1010 IS NULL` this means that the key lookup is skipped for rows where the outer join failed to find a match.
4. The key lookup is executed 179 times and returns 0 rows as nothing matched the predicate.
5. The 36 rows preserved by the outer join where `IsBaseRow1010 IS NULL` never get the predicate evaluated and are eventually output as the result.

When you change the query text to `(select @Notify) = 13005` etc. the `OR` gets represented as a semi join against a `UNION ALL` of two one row virtual tables with the filters applied, rather than as a residual predicate on the lookup, and so the bug is avoided.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation!